# Exponential decay: continuous vs discrete

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Why do people differentiate between *discrete* and *continuous* decay?

If a block of whatever is decaying to half it’s amount ever $x$ years, it is perfectly natural, and continuous to say: $m_0(1/2)^{t/x}=m(t)$ this is a continuous function, not discrete, and it exactly models the decay of such an object. It does not make sense why simply rewriting the same function with base $e$ makes it in some way more continous. Perhaps this can be seen even more clearly as follows:

$$\frac{dm}{dt}=km \implies dt=\frac{dm}{km}=\frac{dm \cdot \ln(1/2)}{km \cdot \ln(1/2)}$$

Integrating,

$$\int{dt}=\frac{1}{k \ln(1/2)} \int{\frac{\ln(1/2)}{m}dm} \implies \left(\frac12 \right)^{\frac{t}{k \ln(1/2)}} \cdot \left (\frac12 \right)^c=m(t)$$

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is very clear. Can you give an example of people differentiating between "discrete and continuous decay?"

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous decay"? Do you mean exponential functions of the form $P e^{rt}$, which describe "continuously compounding interest"?

Comment: @Spencer yes. I understand the difference between compounded interest and continuously compounded but there the “k” applies to something different; the yearly “interest rate” my point is that an equation where the base is not e can still describe something that is compounding continuously.

Comment: Please see this link for exactly what I disagree with(not in terms of the math but the explanations)https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-discrete-vs-continuous-growth/

Comment: You are correct that the article is making an artificial distinction. $2^x$ is a perfectly well defined continuous function of the real variable $x$.

Comment: You should include that article in the text of your question so that we have a better idea of what you are asking.

Comment: Not having read the article, to me this seems a distinction without a difference: for $a\gt0$, $a^{t\lambda}=e^{t\lambda\ln a}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, changing bases from, let's say $2$, to $e$ does not make it more "continuous".

Rather, this is convention, as $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm and much easier to use in calculus.

In addition, converting different bases to base-e allows to easily compare growth/decay of different functions.